# Connection to server timed out in PhoneGap window.location.assign()

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, window.location, connection-timeout

Using PhoneGap on android I get the following error:

> Application Error: The connection to the server timed out. (serverUrl)

while navigating with `window.location.assign(serverUrl)`.  Is there any way to catch this exception inside JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

Add below line of code in your MainActivity.java file:

**super.getIntent().putExtra("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 80000);**